# Converting Java IO Class to Android IO

Tags: java, android, file, io

I want to convert my IO Class from java on Eclipse to the Android API. For some reason it's not working on android!It is giving me a NullPointerException on my Println method. This class is used to create, write, read and open textfiles. My goal is to make all these methods readable on android.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
public class IO {
    private static PrintWriter fileOut;
    private static BufferedReader fileIn;

    public static void createOutputFile(String fileName) {
        try {
            fileOut = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(fileName)));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("*** Cannot create file: " + fileName + " ***");
        }
    }

    public static void openOutputFile(String fileName) {
        try {
            fileOut = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(fileName, true)));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("*** Cannot open file: " + fileName + " ***");
        }
    }

    public static void openOutputFile2(String fileName) {
        try {
            fileOut = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(fileName, false)));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("*** Cannot open file: " + fileName + " ***");
        }
    }



    public static void print(String text) {
        fileOut.print(text);
    }

    public static void println(String text) {
        fileOut.println(text);
        //System.out.println(text);
    }

    public static void closeOutputFile() {
        fileOut.close();
    }

    public static void openInputFile(String fileName) {
        try {
            fileIn = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
            //System.out.println("opening " + fileName);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("***Cannot open " + fileName + "***");
        }
    }

    public static String readLine()
    // throws IOException
    // Note: if there's an error in this method it will return IOException
    {
        try {

            return fileIn.readLine();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "errors";
        }

    }

    public static void closeInputFile() {// throws IOException
        // Note: if there's an error in this method it will return IOException
        try {
            fileIn.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Explain what you mean by "not working". Include error messages. If you're ignoring errors returned by your framework, stop doing that so you can provide the relevant information.  See [ask] for more information.

Comment: I am getting a null pointer exception when I run my code

Comment: Please [edit] that information into your question and include ***where*** in the call-stack that error occurs.

Comment: This class is used when I create or store data in text files. This class worked for me perfectly fine in Java Eclipse, however it's giving me this exception on android. I was hoping someone can understand why. My methods are self explanatory and I wish for someone to guide me on what the syntax is for it to be readable in the android api's eyes.

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting a NullPointerException in `println` then that would be because 'fileOut' is null.

```
public static void println(String text) {
    fileOut.println(text);
    //System.out.println(text);
}
```

You're actually reacting on your second error because you've ignored the first one. In all cases where you set `fileOut` you're swallowing (effectively hiding) the error. E.g.

```
public static void openOutputFile(String fileName) {
    try {
        fileOut = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(fileName, true)));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        //Don't do this, it makes debugging much more difficult.
        //Because the root problem is hidden.
        //So now you have 2 problems to solve.
        //And you've thrown away the information that might have
        //helped to solve the problem in the first place.
        System.out.println("*** Cannot open file: " + fileName + " ***");
    }
}
```

Stop hiding errors, if something goes wrong you need to find out about it. Because invariably, ignoring errors results in more complex errors later down the line.

Fix you bad exception handling, and you'll be able to track down the root problem (probably file not found or a permission error).

Comment: Thank you!!!! I'll look into it ASAP :). And I neverknew that! Our school taught us todo it that way surprisingly.

Comment: HI I just wanted to know, how would I have good exception handling?

Comment: Because what else can I do besides IOException since I'm getting errors using other things

Comment: Proper exception handling is an extensive topic. But a few guidelines: In most cases let an exception bubble up is fine. At the "outer" level it needs to be appropriately logged or reported (depending on kind of application). Only 'react' to an exception if you need to do something as a result of it happening. And usually re-throw to ensure rest of call-stack knows about it. Only swallow an exception if the failure is inconsequential to callers. (You can also swallow if you're providing an API that exposes error information by other means.)

Comment: Probably most important question to ask yourself: Is a client calling this method likely to care about success/failure of my method? If yes, it needs to be able to find out about the error in some way. Exceptions are good but other options do also apply (e.g. Most Windows API functions return a value indicating success/failure and you can call another function to get more detail about an error. This honours the requirement above. But note that in many cases this requires more code on the client and is a common source of bugs when client doesn't do error checking.)